How well does a sea-level engine operating in a vacuum perform compared to a vacuum-optimized engine operating in a vacuum?
A sea-level rocket engine generally has a smaller bell than the equivalent model vacuum-optimized engine - and is perhaps a little bit lighter because of that. I assume that there could be other differences.
Most sea-level engines that are installed on boosters operate from the surface up to the altitude of the rocket at main-engine cut-off (MECO), which generally occurs in what is, for all intents and purposes, a vacuum.
I'd like to learn more about how a sea-level engine's performance (specifically its exhaust velocity) is a function of the rocket's speed and altitude. I'd also like to know how close a sea-level engine comes to achieving the performance of a vacuum-optimized engine of the same base design when the sea-level engine is operated in the vacuum of space.
Also, when the exhaust velocity (or ISP) of a sea-level engine is specified, does that number represent the performance of the engine at sea level, or does it represent the engine's peak performance - that is, the performance of the engine when it is operated in a vacuum?

I know overexpansion robs the engine of some Isp... but it's the expansion that happens outside the bell that represents lost energy, I don't think it actually changes the exhaust velocity much.


I'd like to learn more about how a sea-level engine's performance (specifically its exhaust velocity) is a function of the rocket's speed and altitude.

As far as I'm aware, the rocket's speed doesn't significantly impact exhaust velocity, though interaction of the exhaust plume with the surrounding airstream must have some effect.
For at least the Saturn V's F-1 engine, and I suspect for any rocket engine, the relationship between ambient air pressure and specific impulse is very close to linear1, and air pressure has a generally exponential falloff with altitude.

I'd also like to know how close a sea-level engine comes to achieving the performance of a vacuum-optimized engine of the same base design when the sea-level engine is operated in the vacuum of space.

The best reference point I can think of is the SpaceX Merlin engine, which indeed comes in both a booster version and a vacuum version, with the only significant difference being the size of the nozzle.
It's hard to find a reference that gives the vacuum performance of both the sea-level version of the engine and the vacuum version, and SpaceX has improved the performance of the Merlin several times over the years, but as far as I can tell, it's something like 311 seconds versus 348 seconds, a 12% increase.

Also, when the exhaust velocity (or ISP) of a sea-level engine is specified, does that number represent the performance of the engine at sea level, or does it represent the engine's peak performance - that is, the performance of the engine when it is operated in a vacuum?

Usually both a sea level and vacuum level Isp are given for 1st-stage engines. If not, sea level or vacuum is almost always specified, or understood from context ("at liftoff, the engine produces X thrust with a specific impulse of Y"), but if neither sea level or vacuum is specified, the figure is likely to be the (better) vacuum Isp, particularly in marketing material.

I determined this from the Apollo mission Flight Evaluation Reports, such as this one from Apollo 8. Figure 5-3 shows the measured specific impulse versus elapsed time; I cross-referenced this with the altitude-time plot in figure 4-1.

